# Is it possible to upload a image into server folder without using any severside scripting language

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually i wants to upload a image file into server folder using jquery/javascript and without using any severside scripting. is it possible? pls guide me

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Comment: what possibly could go wrong if it was possible?!... o_0

Comment: No, but you can look at client side databases like TaffyDB.

Comment: if u have any reference url or example pls give

Comment: With JS you can could read the filedata but there's no way to *save* it on the server without some functions server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute answer to that question is no.

A bit about those different sides: the client side languages (html, css, javascript) are all languages that gets executes by your browser. Meaning - on your own computer. You can't perform any operation on somebody else's with them. (accept sending and receiving certain requests).

The server side languages gets executed, not surprisingly, on the server computer! This means that they can execute code to do some operations on the server computer, like for example, save or change files.

This is why client side languages were not designed to do anything on the server, only send various requests (maybe to a server side script that will receive a file and save it locally on the server).

Another important point is security. Just think of the fact that client side scripts are completely exposed to the user. This means that if you could, by that alone, save files to your server from your website, i could copy your code to my own website and that way to save myself some files on your server without you even knowing.